# File input not looping through file

Tags: c++, file-io

Im taking input in from a text file called Enemies.txt.  But there is a problem in that it will only print out the first enemy in the file.

Here is my code:

```
void Enemies :: loadEnemies()
{
    string fileName = "Enemies\\Enemies.txt";
    ifstream infile(fileName);
    string garbage;
    int loadEnemyID;
    string loadEnemyName;
    int loadEnemyStrength;
    int loadExperienceGain;
    string loadWeapon;
    string loadRoom;
    while(infile >> garbage >> garbage >> loadEnemyID
     >> garbage >> garbage >> garbage >> loadEnemyName
     >> garbage >> garbage >> loadEnemyStrength
     >> garbage >> garbage >> garbage >> loadExperienceGain
     >> garbage >> garbage >> garbage >> loadWeapon
     >> garbage >> garbage >> loadRoom >> garbage)
    {
    cout << "Enemy ID: \t\t" << loadEnemyID <<"\n";
    cout << "Enemy Name: \t\t"<< loadEnemyName << "\n";
    cout << "Enemy Strength: \t"<< loadEnemyStrength << "\n";
    cout << "Experience Gain: \t" << loadExperienceGain << "\n";
    cout << "Weapon: \t\t" << loadWeapon << "\n";
    cout << "Room: \t\t\t" << loadRoom << "\n";
    int id = weapon.getWeaponID();
    int weight = weapon.getWeight();
    int damage = weapon.getDamage();
    Weapons w1 (id,loadWeapon, weight,damage);
    int roomID = room.getRoomID();
    string roomExits = room.getRoomExits();
    Rooms r1 (roomID,loadRoom, roomExits);
    Enemies e1 (loadEnemyID,loadEnemyName,loadEnemyStrength,loadExperienceGain,w1,r1);
    enemiesList.Append(e1);
    }
}
```

Enemies.txt

```
Enemy ID: 1.
Enemy Name: Wolves.
Enemy Strength: 5.
Experience Gain: 186.
Weapon Name: Claws.
Room Name: 1.

Enemy ID: 2.
Enemy Name: Cave Bear.
Enemy Strength: 10.
Experience Gain: 302.
Weapon Name: Claws.
Room Name: 4.

Enemy ID: 3.
Enemy Name: Viking.
Enemy Strength: 6.
Experience Gain: 254.
Weapon Name: Longsword.
Room Name: 0.

Enemy ID: 4.
Enemy Name: Criminal.
Enemy Strength: 6.
Experience Gain: 198.
Weapon Name: War Axe.
Room Name: 0.

Enemy ID: 5.
Enemy Name: Ninja.
Enemy Strength: 6.
Experience Gain: 211.
Weapon Name: Katana.
Room Name: 0.

Enemy ID: 6.
Enemy Name: Wild Boar.
Enemy Strength: 3.
Experience Gain: 111.
Weapon Name: Claws.
Room Name: 0.
```

But the funny thing is i have similar code for weapons and it works perfectly.

```
void Weapons :: loadWeapons()
    {
    string fileName = "Weapons\\Weapons.txt";
    ifstream infile(fileName);
    string garbage;
    int loadWeaponID;
    string loadWeaponName;
    int loadDamage;
    int loadWeight;
    while(infile >> garbage >> loadWeaponID >> garbage >> garbage
        >> garbage >> loadWeaponName >> garbage >> loadDamage >> garbage
        >> garbage >> loadWeight >> garbage)
    {
        //cout << "Weapon ID: \t\t"<< loadWeaponID<< "\n";
        //cout << "Weapon Name: \t\t"<< loadWeaponName << "\n";
        //cout << "Damage: \t\t" << loadDamage <<"\n";
        //cout << "Weight: \t\t" << loadWeight << "\n";
        Weapons w1 (loadWeaponID,loadWeaponName,loadDamage,loadWeight);
        weaponsList.Append(w1);
    }
    }
```

Weapons.txt
    ID: 1.
    Weapon Name: Katana.
    Damage: 20.
    Weight: 6.

```
ID: 2.
Weapon Name: Longsword.
Damage: 17.
Weight: 9.

ID: 3.
Weapon Name: WarAxe.
Damage: 22.
Weight: 20.

ID: 4.
Weapon Name: Staff.
Damage: 9.
Weight: 6.

ID: 5.
Weapon Name: Staff.
Damage: 3.
Weight: 0.
```

Comment: Now, I know this isn't strictly C++, but why is it so terrible to use the `fscanf`-function? It's far easier to read, use and debug...at least in my opinion. Anyway, where are you reading the newline between datasets? Plus, you're having one too many garbage at the enemy name. Actually it's just two `garbage` for all datapoints.

Comment: Your weapon one actually counts correctly.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Thanks for the advice.  The infile >> garbage at the end of the while reads in the line between enemies...

Comment: @chris  and does the enemy on not, no ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second and last enemy, you have a name that consists of two words:

```
Enemy Name: Cave Bear.
```

This messes up the parsing when it tries to read in the strength on the next line.

I would recommend using a different parsing method, like `getline` and `split`, instead of trying to abuse `operator>>`. That way, you can put whatever you want on the right side, and it won't mess up the parsing.

Edit:

Also, for some reason, you need to remove the last `>> garbage` from the parse, or it won't work either. However, I still strongly recommend you switch to something else, because the fact that this strange thing happens shows how easily breakable it is.

---

To do `getline` and `split`-like parsing, you would do something like this:

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(file, line)) {
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    std::string left, right;
    std::getline(ss, left, ':'); // Read until the colon
    std::getline(ss, right, '.'); // Read until the period
    std::cout << left << ": " << right << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Maybe not `split`, seeing as how C++ doesn't have one (though Boost does), but going from the colon to the period should work.

Comment: @NeedForSleep it's the "Cave Bear" line that's messing up their parsing, not the "Wild Boar" line (although that one would be a problem as well).

Comment: @chris Well, you can build your own kind of `split` functionality... I agree. Maybe I'll put up an example...

Comment: That works as well. There's a good question on how to split strings on the site. I don't think the `std::split` proposal made it in for C++14.

Comment: I just tested that... I dont think thats it i removed the space in between Cave Bear and it still doesnt loop.  But if the space was a problem it should be fixed right ?